# Is interview-question really a good tag for SO?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I just came across a question about interview questions that was tagged [interview-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interview-question).

This tag doesn't strike me as a very good fit for SO, or at least like a tag that can easily be used to ask questions that are a off-topic. I would say that interview-question related questions are a better match for [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) where there are several pages of `interview` questions.

Luckily there are only 17 [interview-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interview-question) questions on SO at the moment. An amount that can easily be dealt with.

I've gone through all the questions and, in my opinion, the questions that are most on topic for SO are asking for specific solutions to specific problems. They can stand on their on without the tag (in some cases the same question had already been asked without the tag).

The questions that are asking for the best/fastest solution of comparing two solutions, could be a good fit for SO, but they could also be good for either [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) or [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

The questions where the OP is preparing for an interview and is looking for material to prepare for is off topic and better suited somewhere else, maybe [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

**Do you think we should do anything with the [interview-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interview-question) tag on SO? Or should we only migrate the off-topic questions?**

---

My breakdown of all the existing questions:

- [coderpad phone screen for an iOS position: What are good interview questions to ask without xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23926146/coderpad-phone-screen-for-an-ios-position-what-are-good-interview-questions-to) 

  **off-topic:** Asking for possible interview questions the OP could get asked
- [OOAD Elevator System Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23903409/ooad-elevator-system-design)

  **not sure:** asking for a solution to an interview question that the OP was asked
- [OOAD Design for furniture and testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23887409/ooad-design-for-furniture-and-testing) 

  **not sure:** asking for a solution to an interview question that the OP was asked (same OP as above)
- [Print Postorder traversal from given Inorder and Preorder traversals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23880985/print-postorder-traversal-from-given-inorder-and-preorder-traversals)

  **on topic:** the OP is asking for a solution to an specific problem that happens to be an interview question
- [Designing Organizational structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23862836/designing-organizational-structure)

   **note sure:** asking about which out of two solutions is the correct one to an interview question
- [Empty angle brackets in template definition [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23779015/empty-angle-brackets-in-template-definition)

   **on topic: (but dupe)** asking for explanations of a C++ interview question
- [Interview que to write query without using sub query [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668157/interview-que-to-write-query-without-using-sub-query)

   **on topic: (but dupe)** asking for explanations of a database interview question
- [Algorithm to print asterisks for duplicate characters [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651337/algorithm-to-print-asterisks-for-duplicate-characters)

   **note sure (but too broad):** asking if there is a faster solution to this problem
- [Game performance optimization interview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23575999/game-performance-optimization-interview)

   **not sure:** asking what to do if the game is slow but there are no obvious spikes
- [Classic string manipulation interview questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635234/classic-string-manipulation-interview-questions)

   **off-topic:** the OP is preparing for an interview and looking for common questions to prepare for.

*I just realised that my ignored tags prevented me from seeing all the questions but the rest followed a similar pattern.*

Comment: Gah, that's a bunch of 'asking for resources' or 'primarily opinion based' questions there, and the rest should have the tag just removed.

Comment: the way how these questions are seen at Programmers: [Why do interview questions make poor Programmers.SE questions?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6361/31260)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It doesn't matter if a question was sourced from an interview or somewhere else. This is a meta tag, it doesn't say *anything* about the question, and no expert would follow the tag to find interesting questions to answer.

I've removed it from all posts that list it, voting to close any questions that ask for examples or opinions.

[image: Burninated!]

Among these posts, the following may need closing:

Asking for external resources (examples):

- <strike>[Classic string manipulation interview questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635234/classic-string-manipulation-interview-questions)</strike>
- <strike>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23926146/coderpad-phone-screen-for-an-ios-position-what-are-good-interview-questions-to</strike>

Duplicate:

- <strike>[Print Postorder traversal from given Inorder and Preorder traversals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23880985/print-postorder-traversal-from-given-inorder-and-preorder-traversals)</strike>

Comment: @rene: there were 17 posts, I've done 10 already. I'll work from the top, you take the bottom?

Comment: I agree that it's not a tag that is likely to be followed by experts. So it's possibly not a good fit for a tag. Saying that a question is from an interview can be relevant though, because sometimes interviews impose arbitrary constraints which wouldn't be there in reality - e.g. "you must use an abstract base class" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692345/c-sharp-help-i-received-this-during-a-programming-interview/23695461#23695461 . This will change which solutions are acceptable

Comment: @BenAaronson: Sure, but that information can be kept *in the question body*. Arbitrary constraints like what is permissible in a interview question answer are the same as homework constraints, or overbearing security requirements, or what-have-you-not. They don't have a place in tags, mostly.

Comment: Yep, just wanted to put in a reason that the information isn't always entirely irrelevant but I agree it's better suited to the question body.

Comment: would there be some way to auto-burninate things like this?

Comment: @JoeBlow: If a tag is *very* stubborn and being persistently being re-introduced, the developers can blacklist it. That's only for the worst offenders though. Why do you ask?

Comment: @MartijnPieters the tag is back: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/interview-question/info

Comment: @DavidSherret: Gone again. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: @MartijnPieters - the tag reared it's ugly head again; I've squished it for now, but I wouldn't be surprised if it popped back up again before rollover tonight

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: I have it listed in my feed reader so I am alerted normally to catch the tag re-appearing, but you nuked it before I saw the question appear. Thanks!

Comment: This tag appeared again. [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30951891/2301450), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30953874/2301450), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30954762/2301450). Shouldn't it be blacklisted?

Comment: @vaultah blacklisting is really for tags where removing it each time is getting to be too much work. I don't think this tag qualifies, not yet at any rate.