# New tag, job-interview. Yes or no?

Tags: discussion, tags

I see more and more people come here with their job interview questions with requirements that do not match normal way of coding.
Usually it's something like "don't use function xx".

These questions, if not clearly stated it's from a job interview, attract lots of comments and answers that don't help.

I thought maybe if we use a tag for them it's easier to separate them and hint tell people to not answer with function xx.
Also the question is not really a question in the tagged language, well it is but then again your not supposed to use the full language.

And since the questions are generally of a different kind some may enjoy the logic challenge they have and want to be able to filter out only these questions.

What is your opinion?
Do we need it? Can it have a value?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that tag will see questions like *I just got dismissed at my latest job-interview, what did I do wrong* and other personal drama's. Not saying that having bugs in your code or not knowing how to solve a problem in code isn't personal drama ...

Comment: A large proportion of such questions are of little, zero or negative use to future SO users/visitors since they promote poor practices, unrealistic solutions and bad code.  My estimate is 100%.

Comment: @MartinJames That is very true! But as a logic question, or thinking outside the box question they can be quite entertaining to think about. But I absolutly agree with that. For that reason alone they should actually not be here at all.

Comment: Once we had the "interview-question" tag... and we [burninated it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256592/812149).

Comment: Unless it's clearly explained and justified why 'function xx' cannot be used, (eg 'I'm implementing the library on this new architecture'), then I downvote  such questions and often also vote to close, usually as 'Unclear'.

Comment: @Andreas if only entertainment value was a good reason to keep questions on Stack Overflow :) Such questions are better directed at Reddit, IMO.

Answer (score 11):

That's a meta tag. We don't want those.

Read [The Death of Meta Tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) for arguments and more information.

<sub>If you want to discuss the usefulness of meta tags, I suggest you open a separate thread. But this opens up the door for many more tags, such as [homework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework), [beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beginner), etc.</sub>

Comment: I meant a tag on the main site not on meta.

Comment: ... Read the link. I know it's about the main site. Meta tag is a term used for describing these kinds of tags, and has nothing to do with Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: I just read it, but with that logic [arrays] should be removed. Arrays are handled very differently on different languages.

Comment: @Andreas [arrays] could be removed but maybe for different reasons ...

Comment: Yes, the criteria by Jeff to identify them are a bit too broad, but this is a clear one. My personal criterium is: It describes the _context_ in which the question is asked, instead of properties of the actual problem.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth is [tag:chemistry] a meta tag, by that definition?

Comment: @E_net4 Not necessarily, since that could describe the actual content of the question. I've previously called such tags non-programming concepts, and have actually [asked a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361739/7296893) about when and when not to burninate these. It didn't receive much attention, though.

Comment: Fair point. This tag in particular was given more attention [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342959/1233251), and the division was somewhat apparent.