# Should we burninate the [interview] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

<s>The [interview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interview) tag has 22 questions. A selection of them are duplicates or closed questions.</s>

<s>Only 1 question is now left in the [interview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interview) tag. It has been closed.</s>

It is asking for help with interview questions.

The [interview-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interview-question) tag [was burninated back in 2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256594/9606612) as not being relevant to the site.

Is there any need to keep this tag?

Comment: If it's coming back, it should be blocklisted.

Comment: @AmitJoshi: Failed the [interview]

Comment: IIRC, this is also a stuck tag. Would be great if that bug got fixed

Comment: What bug is that, @ZoestandswithUkraine?

Comment: @TRiG [Throw out the \[in\] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417362/6296561) (TL;DR: a thing causes tags to stick around even after they seemingly meet all the auto-deletion criteria)

Comment: [Interview] held with Trogdor

Comment: It came back with 5 questions and I’ve removed the tag from them. Time for blocklisting?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[image: 1]

Answer (score 21):

Yes we should burninate it and blocklist it!

[According to the burnination process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination):

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

No. The interview tag, it seems, is usually used for people asking coding questions from interview questions, which does not describe the contents of the question.

2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

No! Interviews are **not** on-topic! Unless of course the user's question of the coding is very clear and shows work. But even so, there is no need to mention it is an interview coding question.

3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No. There is absolutely no need for one to tag [interview], it's unnecessary information that contributes nothing towards our understanding of the question. I guess it's fine if someone states "I heard this in an interview question", but the tag is not needed.

4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No, there is no difference in asking a question inside or outside an interview. You could say it is the same in all contexts, but either way, it's completely useless and adds no useful additional information to the question.

Comment: I agree the tag should be re-killed (and because the tag has <50 questions, we jump straight to phase 4, so feel free to nuke). To blacklist it, we need a blacklist message before I can escalate

Answer (score 5):

This tag (along with many other tags created on draft Articles) has now been fully cleaned up.

As I indicated in an earlier comment, this was one of several tags that was "stuck" due to being on a draft Article. There were a few issues involved here; originally, Article drafts allowed authors to create tags without needing the [create tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) privilege or preventing blocked tags from being added; in addition, the tags would not be cleaned up by the system automatically, because they were present on Article drafts and could not be removed by anyone without editing permissions on those Articles.

The Collectives team recently went through and did a cleanup of tags created on Article drafts. I worked with the mods to get lists of the affected tags, and shared them with the Collectives team for cleanup; in all, we deleted 79 tags. The reputation requirement is also now being enforced for tag creation via Articles, as is the blocklist. The Collectives team is also working on making changes to the Article draft process to prevent this sort of problem in the future.

Thank you all for your patience!